# How to save woocommerce order details into a new different database table?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am a complete new beginner, started using the woocommerce plugin two weeks ago and created an ecommerce site, the order details are saved and it shows in the admin panel but i want to save the order billing address, user details into a new database with new table.

Is there any help/resources for it??

Comment: please share you new table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `woocommerce_before_save_order_items` hook.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_save_order_items', function() {
    // Do somehting here with the data
}, 10, 2);
```